# How to invoke a method from UIViewController class to Custom UIView class

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, uiview, uibutton

I am not able to call the method which is written in UIViewController(aViewController) from my custom view **bView** .
I want to call the method ***function*** on my button(btn) click in UIView(bView).  But when I click the button, i am getting the following error.

> unrecognized selector sent to instance....

Here is my code:

aViewController.h

```
#import "bView.h"
#import "cViewController.h"

-(void)function;
```

aViewController.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

   bView = [[bView alloc]init];
   [bView makeView];
   bView.bViewController = self;
   [self.view addSubView:bView];

}


-(void)function{

   cViewController *nextViewController = [[cViewController alloc] initWithNibName: nil bundle: nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: nextViewController animated: YES];

}
```

bView.h

```
#import "bViewController.h"

@interface bView : UIView{
   UIButton btn;
   bView *BView;
}

-(void)makeView;
-(void)function;

@property (nonatomic,readonly) UIButton *btn;
@property (assign) UIViewController* aViewController;
```

bView.m

```
#import "bView.h"
#import "aViewController.h"

@impementation bView
@synthesize btn;
@synthesize aViewController;

-(void)makeView{

    btn= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    UIImage *btnimg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn.png"];
    [btn setBackgroundImage:btnimg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(65, 380, 60, 60);
    [self addSubview:btn];
    btn.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [btn addTarget:aViewController action:@selector(function) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Did you try with `strong` for `readonly` in `@property (nonatomic,readonly) UIButton *btn;`?

Comment: switch the two lines ```bView.bViewController = self;``` and ```[bView makeView];```

Comment: Thank you for answering anhtu and Fabio Berger.I could solve it!

Comment: you have your separation of duties backwards and the "who controls who" backwards. A UIViewController controls a UIView, a UIView DOES NOT control a UIViewController, you have to rethink your deseign, there's no way to call to a UIViewController from a UIView since the UIview doesn't have a UINavigationController to control the view,

Comment: you don't need to add the target to the button like you are doing, I'll show you.

Comment: also, you aren't calling to super in your viewDidLoad, this will affect how things work out in a very BIG way, you need to call "[super viewDidLoad]"

Answer (score 1):

You are setting a target to button in `[bView makeView];` method, but at that time `bView`'s `aViewController` is nil because you are setting it only on the next line. So try this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    bView = [[bView alloc]init];
    bView.bViewController = self;
    [bView makeView];
    [self.view addSubView:bView];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! I could solve it by your advice!

Comment: So you can accept the answer then. One more thing, I'd recommend naming classes and respective files starting with uppercase letter.

Comment: Thank you for advice.I have heard that if we name variables,we should name them starting with lower case.So I have done it for classes and respective files...I care about it from now on,thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

this is how you do it, first off, get rid of the "bView.bViewController = self", it doesn't work that way, you shouldn't do this, ever.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
   bView = [[bView alloc]init];
   [bView makeView];
   [self.view addSubView:bView];
   [[bView btn] addTarget:self action:@selector(function) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

function is declared in your UIViewController, not your UIView, so you must call to the button in your viewdidLoad through the bView and then assign it a target and action. I still wouldn't use this method that you are using, but this will do it.

this is the magic:

```
[[bView btn] addTarget:self action:@selector(function) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

AND, remove these lines from the UIView:

```
@property (assign) UIViewController* aViewController;
-(void)function;
[btn addTarget:aViewController action:@selector(function) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

you should remove these if your intent is for the UIViewController to have the function "-(void)function" and I assume this is what you meant. I'm assuming that your "function" is supposed to be called in your UIViewController

for out purposes here, this:

```
 [[bView btn] addTarget:self action:@selector(function) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

is the same thing as this:

```
   [bView.btn addTarget:self action:@selector(function) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and

```
bView.btn = @property (nonatomic,readonly) UIButton *btn;
```

In fact, you don't need to call this button in any UIView, given what you are showing, just call this in your viewDidLoad, like this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton * btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    UIImage *btnimg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn.png"];
    [btn setBackgroundImage:btnimg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(65, 380, 60, 60);
    btn.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:btn];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(function) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

I'm showing you this because you aren't setting up the UIView correctly in the first place by invoking super on it's designated initializer so the best bet now is to just place the button in your viewDidLoad and move on, this is the solution until you understand how the initialize a UIView and set it up correctly. There's a lot of stuff that is wrong with the UIView you have set up and tried to subclass and it's going to be easier for you to just make the button in viewDidLoad and then learn how to subclass correctly in the future.

Comment: Thank you for answering.I didn't know the method "[[bView btn]....".But where should I write it?in aViewController's viewDidLoad?

Comment: it's not a method, that's the variable property you made in your UIView

Comment: this @property (nonatomic,readonly) UIButton *btn; and there's no reason to make it "readonly", just use "nonatomic"

Comment: if this makes it easier, just call "bView.btn" this is the same as "[bView btn]"

Comment: also, you should name your "bView" to something else like "bViewVar", you don't name things the same name as it's class from which it comes from, that's just going to confuse you more.

Comment: I see,it is very useful!I tried to do it,but btn didn't call "function"....I could only push it.

Comment: the "function" is declared in your UIViewController right?

Comment: geeze, and part of the issue here is that your UIView isn't set up right, you have to call to it's super designated initilaizer, you don't even need the "makeview"

Comment: see my answer again, there's no reason to put your UIButton into a UIView if all you have in the UIview is the UIbutton, just do it like I show it in the last part of my answer, don't make this so hard on yourself, you don't need to add a subclass for this unless you are specifically adding a UIButton subclass, but you were adding a UIView subclass and that's not going to work like you want it to

Comment: I'm sorry and you're right,I don't have to use UIView if I have only UIButton.I'm going to make other class's things(UIImageView,UIImage,etc...)So I use UIView.

Comment: if you use UIView for a subclass then you must call to it's super correctly to set it up, you can't subclass stuff unless you know what their default initializers are, you'll have to read documentation on this this, if you want to sub class a button, then subclass a button, but don't subclass a UIVIew that contains a button, it's oinly going to confuse you because it doesn't work like that. You'll eventually get used to this and understand it all, just keep working at it.

Comment: @zmbdr here's a tutorial on subclassing a button: http://blog.ijasoneverett.com/2013/02/a-uibutton-subclass-creating-glossy-buttons-without-images/

Comment: Thank you for sending tutorial,I review it.